# 301 Redirect www.domain to domain.com

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, http-status-code-301

I received a request to redirect a TLD that I believe to be impossible:

```
www.domain ==> domain.com
```

In this situation, the company owns and controls the TLD.  So, for example say I'm trying to redirect a fictional .StackOverflow TLD.  The request would follow the below:

```
www.stackoverflow ==> stackoverflow.com
```

Is this feasible?  I checked to see if popular domains (google, apple, etc.) had this in place and they do not.  If not, can you please provide an explanation as to why not?  I understand how one of these redirects is implemented, more wanted to know about this one off scenario.  I'm struggling finding a definitive answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect all of the requests for www.stackoverflow.com domain to stackoverflow.com by editing the .htaccess file of your website. You need to add the following lines in the beginning of the file so that the redirection is properly set up:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.stackoverflow.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stackoverflow.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Hope this works for you.